# Spring Data Rest Context URI

Tags: spring, rest, uri

I have created a Spring Boot data Rest service ( Not using Spring Web dependencies only Spring Data Rest dependency ) and created different controller methods for the service. For each different controller method, i have to generate Hateaos links and currently doing it by hard coding the path of the links based on the controller method invoked.

Could anyone please let me know if there is anything similar to @Context ( JAX RS  ) annotation in Spring Boot Rest which i can use to get the path of the controller method invoked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post relevant code

Comment: Hi Arun, There is too much code to post on this forum, but ideally would like to know if i can get the context uri in a controller method using Spring rest.  For ex:  public ResponseEntity getInformation(@PathVariable String Id,@Context UriInfo uri, Pageable pageable).            But for that do i have to use the JAX RS libraries to access the context info or can i use any other libraries within the spring rest which would give the uri information.   Thanks

Comment: Hi, I could able to get the request URI by autowiring the HttpServletRequest object. Thanks